# How can I achieve disabling of Soft keyboard and cursor, by touching outside Edit Text with zoomable image on background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am able to display image (zoomable image on touch) on the screen. On click Edit text, soft keyboard is coming up always on the image but sometimes it is reducing image size. Not sure why it is happening and where I need to fix in my XML even though I made AppTheme.PoPupOverlay on Linear layout. On touching Image, the keyboard should close and cursor shall get disappeared. It is currently happening however on touching Edit text, keyboard getting closed and then coming up  which is quite  irritating (happening due to Motion Event that recognize touch and close keyboard while edit text is opening Keyboard ).

Hope I am clear enough. If any queries, kindly let me know.

Below is my XML and Java code that is used for zoomable image.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/back" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/avatarchatmsg"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/addtextzoom"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

                            android:text="ankit shrivastava"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

       >

        <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
            android:id="@+id/myZoomageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:zoomage_restrictBounds="true"
            app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
            app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
            app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
            app:zoomage_zoomable="true"
            app:zoomage_doubleTapToZoom="true"
            app:zoomage_translatable="true"
            app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
            app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newMessageContainer"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:padding="@dimen/_5ssp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.98"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/newMessage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLines="4"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@drawable/right"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


     </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my piece of Java Code for the functionality. Thanks in advance for the support.

```
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction=event.getAction();
           switch(eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            HideSoftKeyBoard.closeKeyboard(ActivityImageVideoChatPick.this);
           
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

           
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;      
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      }
```

Comment: You want to hide keyboard when user tap on  the sceen?

Comment: @Arbaz Thanx for responding. Yes I want keyboard to hide when you tap on the screen. Kindly note I am able to do this (see my Java Function) but the issue is (as explained above) when you touch on Edit Text area, the motion event sense that touch is made and it try to close keyboard. But since you are working on Keyboard, it pop up again giving irritating experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just put onTouchListner on the image and add  code for Keyboard hiding as follows.

```
 public static void closeKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
 activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

  }
```